# how to get the group names back by the ID after grouped by Pandas.groupby().ngroup()

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have grouped my data in pandas by ID

```
df['cityID']=df.groupby(['city']).ngroup()

df =
    names    city       cityID
    ali     Islamabad      0
    john    lahore         1
    aslam   Islamabad      0
    khan    Peshawar       2
    umair   lahore         1

df2 =

    cityID    city
      2        ?
      1        ?
      2        ?
      2        ?
      0        ?
      1        ?
      1        ?
      2        ?
      1        ?
      0        ?
      2        ?
      0        ?
```

after come calculations I got cityIDs I want to convert them back to city names in pandas using python.
populating using the cityIDs

Comment: Could you add some sample data and examples?

Comment: please show your row data, and what you want to achieve.

Comment: for the above example if I have a column on 10 IDs how to assign respective city names based in the IDs

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correct, you want to retrieve a column value based on other column:

```
print(df.loc[df['cityID'] == 1, 'city'].iloc[0])
```

But if what you want is to assign a value to a column depending on a dictionary:

```
d = {0: 'Islamabad', 1: 'lahore', 2: 'Peshawar'}
df["New_col"] = df["cityID"].apply(lambda x: d.get(x))
```

Comment: Isnt there any other way because I have over 100 groups cannot assign everyone in dictionary?

Comment: Try joining both dataframes. `df2=df2.join(df, on='cityID')`